# retrieve set of records based on same field values from store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a store which contains many records. In which one field value will be same for set of records and I have to retrieve other field values which are all have the same field. I do not know how to do this.

my store fields look like this

```
field1: "abc"
field2: "value1"
field3: "value2"

field1: "abc"
field2: "value1a"
field3: "value2a"

field1: "abc"
field2: "value1b"
field3: "value2b"
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Ext.data.Store` [`each()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each) method to loop over all store records and compare if their `field1` value is equal to value you search for. In this case you can collect other field's values:

```
var searchedValue = 'abc';
var field2Values = [];
var field3Values = [];

store.each(function(rec) {
    var recData = rec.getData();
    if (recData['field1'] === searchedValue) {
        field2Values.push(recData['field2']);
        field3Values.push(recData['field3']);
    }
});
```